# Infinite scroll (jScroll) and Ajax product filters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, jquery-jscroll

I have an issue, where I use jScroll for infinite scroll(jScroll), which works fine when the page loads. But the infinite scrolling is not working after an ajax call by a product filter in a search result page.

So here are my filter function called on change ajax call:

```
<script type='text/JavaScript'>
  function filter_onchange()
  {
      $('#imgLoader').show();
      $("#searchResults").load("<?php print $config_baseHREF; ?>search.php?ajax=1&"+$(".ajax").serialize());  
      $('imgLoader').hide();
  }
</script>
```

Here is my jscroll script called from the footer.

```
<script>
        $('.page-section').jscroll({
            autotrigger: true,
            loadingHtml: '<img class="center-block" src="/images/712.gif" alt="Loading" />',
            padding: 20,
            nextSelector: 'a.next',
            contentSelector: '.infinite, .pagination',

        });
</script>
```

So the issue is that after a user has used an filter(calling the function filter_onchange()) the jScroll stops working. In console I get the error:

```
TypeError: data is undefined

if (!data.waiting && iTotalHeight + _options.padding >= $inner.outerHeight()) {
```

jScroll.js

```
/*!
 * jScroll - jQuery Plugin for Infinite Scrolling / Auto-Paging
 * http://jscroll.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2011-2013, Philip Klauzinski
 * http://klauzinski.com/
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jscroll.com/#license
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 *
 * @author Philip Klauzinski
 * @version 2.3.4
 * @requires jQuery v1.4.3+
 * @preserve
 */
(function($) {

    'use strict';

    // Define the jscroll namespace and default settings
    $.jscroll = {
        defaults: {
            debug: true,
            autoTrigger: true,
            autoTriggerUntil: false,
            loadingHtml: '<small>Loading...</small>',
            padding: 0,
            nextSelector: 'a:last',
            contentSelector: '',
            pagingSelector: '',
            callback: false
        }
    };

    // Constructor
    var jScroll = function($e, options) {

        // Private vars and methods
        var _data = $e.data('jscroll'),
            _userOptions = (typeof options === 'function') ? { callback: options } : options,
            _options = $.extend({}, $.jscroll.defaults, _userOptions, _data || {}),
            _isWindow = ($e.css('overflow-y') === 'visible'),
            _$next = $e.find(_options.nextSelector).first(),
            _$window = $(window),
            _$body = $('body'),
            _$scroll = _isWindow ? _$window : $e,
            _nextHref = $.trim(_$next.attr('href') + ' ' + _options.contentSelector),

            // Check if a loading image is defined and preload
            _preloadImage = function() {
                var src = $(_options.loadingHtml).filter('img').attr('src');
                if (src) {
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.src = src;
                }
            },

            // Wrap inner content, if it isn't already
            _wrapInnerContent = function() {
                if (!$e.find('.jscroll-inner').length) {
                    $e.contents().wrapAll('<div class="jscroll-inner" />');
                }
            },

            // Find the next link's parent, or add one, and hide it
            _nextWrap = function($next) {
                var $parent;
                if (_options.pagingSelector) {
                    $next.closest(_options.pagingSelector).hide();
                } else {
                    $parent = $next.parent().not('.jscroll-inner,.jscroll-added').addClass('jscroll-next-parent').hide();
                    if (!$parent.length) {
                        $next.wrap('<div class="jscroll-next-parent" />').parent().hide();
                    }
                }
            },

            // Remove the jscroll behavior and data from an element
            _destroy = function() {
                return _$scroll.unbind('.jscroll')
                    .removeData('jscroll')
                    .find('.jscroll-inner').children().unwrap()
                    .filter('.jscroll-added').children().unwrap();
            },

            // Observe the scroll event for when to trigger the next load
            _observe = function() {
                _wrapInnerContent();
                var $inner = $e.find('div.jscroll-inner').first(),
                    data = $e.data('jscroll'),
                    borderTopWidth = parseInt($e.css('borderTopWidth'), 10),
                    borderTopWidthInt = isNaN(borderTopWidth) ? 0 : borderTopWidth,
                    iContainerTop = parseInt($e.css('paddingTop'), 10) + borderTopWidthInt,
                    iTopHeight = _isWindow ? _$scroll.scrollTop() : $e.offset().top,
                    innerTop = $inner.length ? $inner.offset().top : 0,
                    iTotalHeight = Math.ceil(iTopHeight - innerTop + _$scroll.height() + iContainerTop);

                if (!data.waiting && iTotalHeight + _options.padding >= $inner.outerHeight()) {
                    //data.nextHref = $.trim(data.nextHref + ' ' + _options.contentSelector);
                    _debug('info', 'jScroll:', $inner.outerHeight() - iTotalHeight, 'from bottom. Loading next request...');
                    return _load();
                }
            },

            // Check if the href for the next set of content has been set
            _checkNextHref = function(data) {
                data = data || $e.data('jscroll');
                if (!data || !data.nextHref) {
                    _debug('warn', 'jScroll: nextSelector not found - destroying');
                    _destroy();
                    return false;
                } else {
                    _setBindings();
                    return true;
                }
            },

            _setBindings = function() {
                var $next = $e.find(_options.nextSelector).first();
                if (!$next.length) {
                    return;
                }
                if (_options.autoTrigger && (_options.autoTriggerUntil === false || _options.autoTriggerUntil > 0)) {
                    _nextWrap($next);
                    if (_$body.height() <= _$window.height()) {
                        _observe();
                    }
                    _$scroll.unbind('.jscroll').bind('scroll.jscroll', function() {
                        return _observe();
                    });
                    if (_options.autoTriggerUntil > 0) {
                        _options.autoTriggerUntil--;
                    }
                } else {
                    _$scroll.unbind('.jscroll');
                    $next.bind('click.jscroll', function() {
                        _nextWrap($next);
                        _load();
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            },

            // Load the next set of content, if available
            _load = function() {
                var $inner = $e.find('div.jscroll-inner').first(),
                    data = $e.data('jscroll');

                data.waiting = true;
                $inner.append('<div class="jscroll-added" />')
                    .children('.jscroll-added').last()
                    .html('<div class="jscroll-loading">' + _options.loadingHtml + '</div>');

                return $e.animate({scrollTop: $inner.outerHeight()}, 0, function() {
                    $inner.find('div.jscroll-added').last().load(data.nextHref, function(r, status) {
                        if (status === 'error') {
                            return _destroy();
                        }
                        var $next = $(this).find(_options.nextSelector).first();
                        data.waiting = false;
                        data.nextHref = $next.attr('href') ? $.trim($next.attr('href') + ' ' + _options.contentSelector) : false;
                        $('.jscroll-next-parent', $e).remove(); // Remove the previous next link now that we have a new one
                        _checkNextHref();
                        if (_options.callback) {
                            _options.callback.call(this);
                        }
                        _debug('dir', data);
                    });
                });
            },

            // Safe console debug - http://klauzinski.com/javascript/safe-firebug-console-in-javascript
            _debug = function(m) {
                if (_options.debug && typeof console === 'object' && (typeof m === 'object' || typeof console[m] === 'function')) {
                    if (typeof m === 'object') {
                        var args = [];
                        for (var sMethod in m) {
                            if (typeof console[sMethod] === 'function') {
                                args = (m[sMethod].length) ? m[sMethod] : [m[sMethod]];
                                console[sMethod].apply(console, args);
                            } else {
                                console.log.apply(console, args);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        console[m].apply(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                    }
                }
            };

        // Initialization
        $e.data('jscroll', $.extend({}, _data, {initialized: true, waiting: false, nextHref: _nextHref}));
        _wrapInnerContent();
        _preloadImage();
        _setBindings();

        // Expose API methods via the jQuery.jscroll namespace, e.g. $('sel').jscroll.method()
        $.extend($e.jscroll, {
            destroy: _destroy
        });
        return $e;
    };

    // Define the jscroll plugin method and loop
    $.fn.jscroll = function(m) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data('jscroll'), jscroll;

            // Instantiate jScroll on this element if it hasn't been already
            if (data && data.initialized) {
                return;
            }
            jscroll = new jScroll($this, m);
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what is wrong here - is it the placement of the scripts ?

In the filter ajax call, I do call the footer again so the jScroll script is part of the load in the filter function called.

Comment: Where is the variable `data` defined?

Comment: @BrandonNguyen which of the variables ?

Comment: Aff wait, it's defined in jscroll.js - I will add the file here. The jscroll fill is added in the footer.

Comment: See  // Constructor
    var jScroll = function($e, options) {

        // Private vars and methods
        var _data = $e.data('jscroll'),

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem @TroelsJohannesen? I am in a same situation now.